# avoid trap representation with memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

Please consider the following code:

```
float float_value = x; // x is any valid float value
int int_value = 0;
size_t size = sizeof(int) < sizeof(float) ? sizeof(int) : sizeof(float);
memcpy(&int_value, &float_value, size);
```

As far as i know this could result in an trap representation. My questions:

1. Is that true?
2. If not, why?
3. If not, is there another way avoiding a possible trap representation?

Comment: It basically looks like evil undefined behavior.  Int and float may be of different sizes.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to see the binary representation of a float?  memcpy() is a nuclear bomb solution where the simple hammer of an assign with a typecast would do.

Comment: You could use an unsigned int and avoid any problems.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan An assign with a typecast? Do you mean `int_value = (int) float_value;`? No, that does not show you the representation, although there is a solution with an union.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  Float rounding would kill that.  Union is the better choice.

Comment: @all i just need a valid c99 way to get a hash value out of other types

Comment: @TJD is that true? is though only unsigned char never trap

Comment: @Johannes, I think you are strictly correct, although I think in practice it is extremely unlikely find issues with representing unsigned ints

Comment: Michael: memcpy is the way to go, and stdc says so

Comment: @kaizer.se: The standard guarantees that a union will also work. (§6.5.2.3, footnote 82 in TR3).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sanctioned way which won't produce any trap representation is

```
unsigned char obj[sizeof float];
memcpy(obj, &float_value, sizeof float);
```

Then you can use the bytes of the object representation to build your desired `int`.

But using fixed-width integers as mentioned by Stephen Canon is better - unless you have a weird `float` size.

Comment: Actually, for the specific purpose of hashing, I quite like this solution.

Comment: @kaizer.se Thanks for the link to the standard.

Comment: Why to do use `malloc`. `char buf[sizeof float]` would completely be sufficient.

Comment: @Jens: 6.2.6.1.4 seems to require `unsigned char`, not just `char`.

Comment: @sarnold, ah, sorry, yes I meant `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Jens Why malloc? Umm, just because I had malloc on my mind. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `memcpy` if you only want to inspect the values there. The easiest is to just cast

```
unsigned char const* p = &float_object;
```

pointer cast to all `char` types is always guaranteed to give something valid with which you can do simple arithmetic. You are safe as long as you do dereferencing inside the bounds given by sizeof `float_object`.

If you want to treat that as a number the safest is to chose an unsigned integer of fixed width, most probably `uint32_t`. If you know that the width requirements are fulfilled, this should give you everything you need.

As mentioned this works well as long as you don't write through that pointer. Then the aliasing rules for pointers can have the optimizer go wrong afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that could result in a trap representation.  As for how to avoid it:

- Assert that `sizeof(int32_t) == sizeof(float)`
- Use `int32_t` instead of `int`.

The fixed-width integer types may not admit trap representations.  Specifically, the standard requires that they have no padding bits, and you cannot have a trap representation without padding.

Comment: are you sure about that? i though only *unsigned char* never traps. could you please quote C99? thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Johannes: §7.18.1.1 "The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation."  Because there are no padding bits, all N bits are *value* bits, thus every combination of bits has a value defined by the standard and cannot be a trap representation.

Comment: @Stephen, you could have a trap representation without padding, namely  the restrictions that you cite still leave two possible values for `INTXX_MIN`. But the standard closes this loophole by fixing what the value has to be in addition. In the copy I have it even looks that this was added later with one of the updates.

Comment: @JensGustedt: You're overlooking the requirement that a twos-complement representation is used.  There is a unique `INT32_MIN`.  (as specified in §7.18.2.1)

Comment: @Stephen, this was exactly the point in the standard I was referring to. Two's complement alone doesn't guarantee that, the standard explicitly allows "the value with sign bit 1
and all value bits zero" to be a trap representation.
You need to fix the min value in addition to that value in addtion. This information is missing in your answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt: That's addressed in §7.18.2.1, which requires that `INTN_MIN` is exactly -2**(n-1).  I assume that's what you are getting at.

Comment: @Stephen, yes exactly, this is what I was saying from the start, and what was missing from your answer.